# What is another name for a storage closet?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

The room in question is carpeted, has bare wooden shelves, and is located within a suite on the second floor of an office complex. It is referred to as a 'shed'.  If it were outside as a roofed, stand-alone structure, it would definitely qualify as a shed but in this instance it doesn't seem accurate.

What are some alternative terms for a walk-in closet/room that stores supplies (including scientific instruments, batteries, yard tools,storage containers, etc.,)?

Comment: Does the door open to the outside or the inside of the building? Or to the interior of the suite or to a common hallway?

Comment: @Jim it opens to the inside of a lounge/kitchen room in an office suite on the second floor of a building.

Comment: That sounds like a ***pantry***  or as David says, a storeroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about storeroom?

> A room in which items are stored.

Or repository:

> A place where or receptacle in which things are or may be stored.

Answer (score 5):

I would add **stockroom**

> A room in which quantities of goods are stored. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stockroom)

Comment: I think of a stockroom as being in a store and holding the stock/merchandise not on display in the storefront.

Comment: @Jim The contents listed could be stock for a business.

Comment: the list of items sure sounds more like tools and supplies routinely used by the business itself rather than for sale

Comment: @Tom22 they are tools used out in the field and supplies used in the office by the company itself